# what's the circuit on the two stage amp's left hand side?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I want to ask what is the circuit in the left hand side,i know the right hand is a kind of two stage amp.After i know what is in the left, i may read some information about it.Thank you
[image]

Comment: i know the right hand side is two stage,but i don't know what is that Pmos doing

Comment: Neither does anyone else, the picture of the schematic is too small to read anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of the [wilson current mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_current_mirror) to bias the tail current source of the differential pair. This current mirror incorporates negative feedback to set the current. The two top transistors are probably used to 'spend' some voltage so the voltages of the lower transistors and the tail current source match better.